# How can I enable Javascript in Firefox, or what is stopping it from being enabled?

Tags: windows-xp, firefox, javascript

XP3
Firefox 3.6.9

The Superuser and other sites state that I don't have Javascript enabled. I also am unable to view certain videos on the web and they say that I must have Javascript enabled.

I have searched the net and followed instructions as to enable this, but still no joy.

Can anyone point me to a solution?

Thanks,
Regards,

EDIT: If it is important, here is the site I am trying: http://www.thestar.com/news/torontog20summit/article/922039--siu-reopens-g20-case-after-photos-surface

Comment: What plugins do you have installed?

Comment: Adblock plus 1.3.3
Canadian english dictionary 2.0.0
Fastestfox 4.1.8
Java console 6.0.17, 6.0.20, 6.9.16, 6.0.22, 6.0.23,
Java Quick Starter 1.0
Microsoft .NET Framework Assistant 1.2.1
Open Download 1.0.0
Quick Search 0.6.0
Tab Mix Plus 0.3.8.4
TubeStop 1.5

Comment: I have now successfully upgraded to 3.6.13. There is no change in results, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

(3.6.9 is outdated.)

Tools | Options | Content -> Enable JavaScript.

What is it that you are trying at your link?

Comment: This is where I have everything enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Start FF in Safe Mode.

http://kb.mozillazine.org/Safe_mode

If your page works as expected, then look at your extensions for a conflict.